# Xorg error ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, nvidia, xorg

Good day. I am posting this from my phone as the Ubuntu laptop has no networking available.

The system worked for about three months. Problems began with kernel 4.4.0-108. I deleted both kernel 108 and 109 upgraded to 112 and kept 104 as the back up. 
The problem is the system freezes upon the splash screen and a boot loop occurs. If i use nomodeset the system freezes with the vg root recovery message . Using 104 kernel the system goes into low graphics mode.

The only way the system will boot is if I do a system recovery. Then dpkg then boot only with kernel 104. Upon booting I have no network. Commands in terminal comes up with connection refused. In the error reporting there is a xorg error with screens not found.

I also tried recovery from deja dup. I know the nvidia file needs updating. But with no networking this is not possible.

I attempted to use the live USB to either do a recovery or reinstall. I understand that all the system needs to do is update. The live USB which I used to install everything is 14.04 however the live USB is not booting. Freezing in the splash screen.

What are my options. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to fix this about a month now.

Did

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Got the message

```
Note, selecting ' nvidia- prime' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia common' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note , selecting ' nvidia - libopencl1-dev' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note , selecting 'ubuntu- drivers common' instead of 'nvidia-common' 
Package, 'nvidia-prime' is not installed , so not removed
Package ' nvidia-libopencl1-dev ' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded 0 newly installed 0 to remove and 2 not installed
```

Willing to reinstall everything and start over. However the live USB is also freezing. What options do I have ?

Ubuntu is the only OS on the system. The OEM install from the live USB also freezes.